# Parameter comparing won't work

Tags: javascript

Everything works just fine - everything except this one if-else-statement:

```
    else if ((day = 0 || day = 6) && (hour <= 19)) {
  greeting = "We wish you a nice weekend and a nice " +
  Weekdays[day] + ".";
  }
```

Firefox's Error Message: 'ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side'

..it should be really easy but till now I coudn't find the problem.

Thanks for helping and have a nice day!

Comment: You're using `=` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `==` for comparison(by `value`) and `=` for assigning values.

So in your case, it should be:

```
 ...
 else if ((day == 0 || day == 6) && (hour <= 19)) {
   greeting = "We wish you a nice weekend and a nice " +
   Weekdays[day] + ".";
 }
 ...
```

If you need to compare by both `type` and `value`, you should use `===`

**In short:**

```
var a = 10; // assigns value 10 to variable `a`

"1"==1      // true => Since == compares by value

"1"===1     // false => Since === compares by both type and value. In this case although value is 1, both are of different types (string and integer)
```

Comment: Though it should really be `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: @killgar I looked that up now and it seems like you can use both. The == is just 'equal' and the === is 'strict equal' [Link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)